# how to make a Switch unclickable in android in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have this xml layout, I want to make the switch element unclickable (disabled) so that when a user tries to press it, it doesn't work. how can I do this?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/english"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Set clickable attribute to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:enabled="false"` to your Switch element.

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    **android:enabled="false"** />
```

Comment: android:enabled="false" will turn off that switch by default, right? or it will make it unclickable?

Comment: @AlishaAbro it will make it unclickable. To change the default value of switch, add "android:checked" attribute and set it to true/false.